# Which of these Network Interfaces is my Wireless?

Tags: wireless, networking

Since I upgrade to 12.04 I cannot seem to find wlan0 anymore for my wifi network interface. Here is a snapshot of my interfaces after typing ifconfig and iwconfig into the terminal. If Anybody could quickly tell me which one is my wireless interface is I would much appreciate it. I am trying to set up hostapd.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the `iwconfig` output you can see that eth0 has "No wireless extensions", so the wireless network interface is eth1.

Comment: Thank you very much! I assumed it was, i wanted to be sure!

Comment: @Alex090391 Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted". See http://askubuntu.com/about